# javascript - laravel reset form

Tags: javascript, jquery, laravel, forms

My form reset button doesnt reset my form. I added a class for my dropdowns to be hidden unless theres a change in select. The current behavior is clicking the reset button will only reset its values but doesn't hide the supposed to be hidden dropdowns.

**my reset button**

```php
{!! Form::reset('Reset', ['class' => 'btn btn-primary', 'id' => 'btn-click']) !!}
```

**script i used**

```js
$('form').reset(function (event){
      $(document).ready(function(){
       $("#btn_click").click(function(){
       $(".dropdown").addClass("no-display");
    });
    });
```

Can't find any docu about resetting a form with laravel can anyone help

Comment: $(document).ready at first.......

Comment: yes, the script is under `(document).ready`

Comment: First: **$(document).ready(function(){**, after **$('form').reset(function (event){**

Comment: changed my code into this but still no changes
```
$('form').reset(function (event) {
      $(".reset-btn").click(function(){
        $("#Form").trigger("reset");
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#btn_click").click(function() {
       $(".dropdown").addClass("no-display");
    });
});
```

This code will execute once the document is ready, meaning it has been loaded, then it will set a **click** event handler for **#btn_click** which when clicked will add **no-display** class to the dropdown.

**Note:** There is no event handler named as **reset** as you have written here:

```
$('form').reset(function (event){
```

Comment: Glad to know it helped you! :)